# How to remove the restricted file from git commit?

Tags: git

I was using the git enterprise in company. When I '**git push**', it told me the following error.

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 289, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (264/264), done.
Writing objects: 100% (289/289), 9.95 MiB | 207.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 289 (delta 37), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (37/37), completed with 4 local objects.
remote: hooks/xxxx.sh: failed with exit status 1
remote: refs/heads/master 347a6011604730df57a348f8aa166b747d9684fe 4f6d30e187b4d20ea5ba56bd9babcdf3a3b3021b
remote: We have restricted committing abc.zip filetype. 
remote: ********RESTRICTED********
remote: abc.zip
remote: **************************
To https://gitprod.xxx
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitprod.xxx
```

How to remove the zip file and push again, I tried a couple of ways but did not find the correct way. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried please? Did you do `git remove`, `git commit`, and then `git push`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+file+history

Answer (score 1):

You accidentally staged that restriced file type, so you need to unstaged it.

Use:

```
git reset -- <filePath>
```

OR

```
git rm --cached <filePath>
```

Just replace < filePath > with the actual path of the zip file.

Then, try to commit and push again.
(But don't include that file in your commit.)

Comment: After that, it should not be commited normally, `git commit --amend` should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since your last (unpushed) commit contains the unwanted file, we need to undo it, then commit again without it :

```
# undo last commit (but keep changes in working tree)
git reset --soft HEAD^

# unstage your .zip file
git reset HEAD path/to/abc.zip

# commit and push again
git commit -m "Message here"
git push
```

(No need to push with `--force` since last push was rejected.)

Answer (score 1):

If this file was added into your last commit, **it needs to be removed from this commit** with `git  commit --amend`.

Before amending just remove the file with `git rm --cached abc.zip`.